# In C can we use operators such as :: or -> to access predefined methods in header files?

Tags: c++, c

I will have two files. One `header.h` file and second one is `main.c` file.

Now, how to make a header.h file with methods written in C (such as print test etc), then in `main.c` file, how can I access them with operators such as `::` or `->`

@file: main.c

```
#include "header.h"; // sorry i made mistake before

int main()
    {
      A::myStaticFunction();

      // OR

      A->myInstanceFunction();

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Where did you get the `import` from? What is `.A` supposed to mean? Is this C or C++?

Comment: is it C++ CLI i.e. managed C++ by any chance?

Comment: @Asha: I think :: is only possible with C++. But C++ is very hard, i want to do only :: and -> with C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to do it completely in C.
>   <sup>(from @Sonia's comment on @Als' answer)</sup>

Not completely possible. What you got there is C++ code, it can't be emulated in C in exactly that way.

In C, a `struct` can't have functions, only function pointer and also can't have **any** `static` members at all. So, no `::` for you in that regard. Your other example, on @David's answer, is most likely an `enum`:

```
typedef enum _H323Connection{
  AnswerCallNow,
  AnswerCallLater,
  IgnoreCall,
  /* examples */
}H323Connection;
```

Now, to get one of those values inside the enum you can just use the name (`IgnoreCall`) or qualify it with the enum's name (`H323Connection::IgnoreCall`).

The `->` operator, however, is totally possible.

```
typedef struct _sA{
  // function pointer
  void (*AnswerCall)(struct _sA*, H323Connection);
  // variables...
}sA;

void sA_AnswerCall(sA* self, H323Connection callmode){
  // do something with self
  switch(callmode){
    case AnswerCallNow: /* ... */ break;
    case AnswerCallLater: /* ... */ break;
    case IgnoreCall: /* ... */ break;
  }
}

int main(){
  sA* pA = (sA*)malloc(sizeof(sA));

  // assign function pointer;
  pA->AnswerCall = sA_AnswerCall;
  // call it and pass "this" (the object the function operates on)
  pA->AnswerCall(pA, H323Connection::AnswerCallNow);
  // in C++ ---- ^^ would be the "this" pointer and 
  // would be passed secretly by the compiler

  free(pA);
}
```

Comment: excellent you really know what you are doing. I appreciate it. But i dont get it yet do you mean :: i can only use in C++? Not in ANSI-C or Objective-C?

Comment: @Sonia: As other answers explain, it is the scope resolution operator. In C, there are not many scopes. But you just gave me an idea to solve this static function problem. Brb. :)

Comment: @Sonia: Nope, my experiment failed, you can't have static members in C and as such no static member functions (not even emulated with static function pointers).

Comment: PHP is an interpreter written in C, but PHP-syntax itself is not dependent on C's language features.  The interpreter reads a line from the PHP file, translates that code into a C data-structure, and then executes the desired operation.  Scope-resolution and other "non-C" features are nothing more than data-structures like hash-tables, linked-lists, etc., all of which can be implemented using structures that have `void*` data-members pointing to allocated PHP objects on the heap, and labels (i.e., enums, etc.) in order to properly interpret the PHP objects being pointed to by the `void*`'s.

Answer (score 1):

You should start with a C tutorial, as this is very basic, and for sure explained in all tutorials.

```
// header.h
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
void foo();
#endif

// main.c
#include "header.h"
int main() {
   foo();
}
```

With `foo` being *defined* in a different .c file that gets linked together.

Now it seems, from the code, that you are not talking about C, but rather C++, and that you have a class defined in the header:

```
// header.h
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
struct A {
   static void foo();
   void bar();
};
#endif

// main.c
#include "header.h"
int main() {
   A::foo();        // static method
   A a;
   a.bar();         // non-static method
}
```

Again, the methods defined in a .cpp file and linked together.

Comment: Hello David, thank you. I think i explained wrong. I am reading a code where its using such things so i wanted to make a small test first how it works example: connection->AnsweringCall(H323Connection::AnswerCallNow);   Where i dont see in what is that -> and :: is doing?

Comment: @Sonia - How the method signature of `AnsweringCall` looks like ?

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about the `->` and `::` operators, they are used in different ways.

First is the `::` operator, it is used in two ways

1. Namespace clarification.  The `::` operator is used to specify something within a namespace without having the `using` keyword.  For example, if you were using the STL version of the `vector<T>` class, you can access it directly by using `std::vector<T>`
2. Static class member access.  If you have static members declared for a class (functions or variables) they are accessed via `ClassName::memberName`.

Secondly, the `->` operator is the same as the `.` operator, except it is used for pointer objects.  Example

```
struct myStruct {
    int x,y;
};

int main(void)
{
    myStruct aStaticVersion;
    aStaticVersion.x = 0;
    myStruct *aPointerVersion = new myStruct();
    aPointerVersion->x = 0; //Acts the same as aStaticVersion.x = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

As Xeo has reminded me, the `::` operator has a third usage, to specify members of an `enum`  EX:

```
enum myEnum {
  firstValue = 0,
  secondValue,
  thirdValue
};

int main(void)
{
   myEnum enumValue = myEnum::secondValue;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`A::myStaticFu`nction();` is possible if myStaticFunction() is a static function in class A.

`A->myInstanceFunction();` is not possible you need to create a pointer of class A to call its member function in this fashion.

// header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
class A
{
    public:
    static void myStaticFunction()
    {
         //do some stuff
    }

    void myInstanceFunction()
    {

    }
};

void doSomething()
{

}
#endif

//main.cpp

int main()
{
    //Call static function inside a class, no need of class instance or pointer
    A::myStaticFunction();

    //Call member function inside a class, need a class instance or pointer
    A *ptr = new A();
    ptr->myInstanceFunction();
    //or
    A obj;
    obj.myInstanceFunction()

    //call a global function outside the class, no need of class instance or pointer
    doSomething();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: "@file: main.c" - so, no C++ stuff, including classes.

Comment: @xeo: Q is tagged C++, besides how are you going to use `->` or `::` without C++?

Comment: Thank you. Yes Xeo is correct. I would like to do it completely in C. But anyway thank you so much, its very nice example you wrote in 30 seconds? You must be brilliant.

Comment: Nevermind my last comment, but both `->` and `::` are possible in C.

Answer (score 0):

In C and derivates you include header files with the #include pre-processor directive. This does nothing else than interpreting the included file. It is the same effect as if you copy-n-pasted the content of the header file into your source code.
You cannot access header files or parts of it by name like for example in python.

Comment: Hello Hyperbereus, Thank you, i am very sorry i really forgot it, it was my java lesson making me confused.

Answer (score 0):

The `::` is the scope resolution operator ... you use it to create qualified names from a scope/namespace in C++ using a syntax like `namespace::variable_name`.  For instance, if you had

```
int a_var;

namespace nested
{
    int a_var;
}
```

then in order to access the fully qualified name of the two different versions of `a_var`, you'd have `::a_var` (meaning that it's in the global scope), and `nested::a_var`.  If you were to try and call a variable named `a_var`, C++ would default to the current scope first.  If you wanted to get another version of `a_var` in a different namespace, you would have to qualify that name.  Here is an example using two functions that you might define after the above code:

```
void func_a()
{
    a_var = 5; //<== accesses ::a_var in the global namespace
}

void func_b()
{
    nested::a_var = 5; <== accesses nested::a_var and not ::a_var
}
```

So you can see just assigning a value 5 to `a_var` does not get you the version of `a_var` in the `nested` namespace.  If you want that alternate version of `a_var`, you'll have to qualify the name using the scope resolution operator.

Scope resolution also applies to classes and structs ... both of those types of objects create a namespace scope for their static data-members and functions as well, so if you had declared some object `class Foo`, and you wanted access to some static data member `int b_var`, you could gain access to it by writing the fully qualified name `Foo::b_var`.

The `->` operator is a pointer dereference operator for compound types (i.e., classes and structs).  I works the same way it does in traditional C, where if you had a pointer to an object of some type `T`, then `T->method_function()` or `T->non_static_variable` would dereference the pointer of type `T*` and access the appropriate non-static member function or non-static data variable.  It's basically the same as writing `(*T).method_function()` or `(*T).non_static_variable`.